# Android embedded barcode scanner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to build an Android app, like a Point Of Sale machine. 
On opening the app, one corner of the app should have the camera view, listening for barcode (battery drain part understandable and that's acceptable in this case). Remaining part of the app should show the items added to the cart.

The use case here is to keep listening for barcode in one part of UI and remainng part of the app shows the scanned content. There should not be any switch between the apps main screen and barcode scanner.

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Please Snippet your code

Comment: We really dont have anything started with this barcode scanning part to share the snippet. We've considered the embeded options here in  https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded. But couldn't find a solution, which can keep running the camera mode in a corner of the main screen (You can imagine a plain android layout, having camera mode running in right bottom corner of it)